# JavaScript current date is before other datetime

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, datetime, filter

I am fetching some event objects from a Java application and wish to filter them, so they only consists of events that are having open doors (start time) after the current time.
The Java application open doors are of LocalDateTime

So far I found this as a opportunity:

```
events.filter((event) => {
     return Date.now() <= Date.parse((event._openDoors).toString())
});
```

Is this correctly and if so is there an smarter way?

Comment: Why the "javascript" tag? Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: Never use either `Date` class bundled with Java. Both are terribly flawed. Both are legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: I use JavaScript tags, because it is JavaScript. I'm just fetching an event object from an Java application. Found out from another that Date is outdated, so that might be true.

Answer (score 4):

> The Java application open doors are of LocalDateTime

No, this is not correct. [`LocalDateTime#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now--) returns the current date-time from the system clock in the default time-zone. You should use [`Instant#now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--). An `Instant` is an instantaneous point on the time-line.

You can use `Instant.now().toEpochMilli()` to get the number of milliseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense that .toEpochMilli() should be used for comparing value. Havn't tried Instant instead of Date before, but could be that is more efficient. Thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome, @Laustrup The `java.util` Date-Time API (e.g. `java.util.Date`) and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). The `LocalDateTime` class is also from the modern date-time API.